# How do I set a friend of a friend tagged on a photo I posted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I shared a photo with my friends only. I'd like a friend of a friend to see a photo or a photoset. (He is not my friend.)

To do that, I set my photo with friends-only privacy and tag a friend of my friend. Curiously, it does not work for everybody. Indeed, usually I can reach such people in the list. How can fix it?

I know another way to make it work is to ask my friend to tag his friend on my photo, but I'd like to do it directly.

Comment: Why not add him as a friend?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you are able to tag a person depends on his/her privacy settings.

Try typing the persons name followed by either + or @ to see if the option to tag the particular person presents itself.

The best thing to do here would actually send a friend request to the person and friend him on Facebook. If you want to tag someone in Facebook, you are likely to know them enough to friend them on Facebook.

Comment: thanks for reply.
It confirm I can't fix it from my side.
Friend concept is sometime more than the simple word meaning.
For some reason, we are not friend on FB but, have contacts and some occasion to share pics and messages.

Comment: the case is that if the user have enable restriction so that friends alone able to tag the photo .You wont be able to get the name of user listed while tagging friends of friends in your photo.

Answer (score 0):

Key in his name - FB MAY present you with the correct person.